# Classical momentum of a subatomic particle

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, quantum-measurements

If I measure the momentum of a quantum particle, can I use the relativistic momentum equation to deduce what the particle speed was at the moment of measurement? Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, velocity is the momentum over the mass, so if the mass is given we can find velocity

Comment: Yes, but qm is in nonrelativistic regime, so gamma would be about 1

Comment: Note that the question specifically asked about the relativistic momentum equation.

Comment: @PM2Ring You’re misinterpreting what I’m saying. What you’re referring to is just classical/quantum field theory. QM by itself usually refers to nonrelativistic particle physics (think schrodinger equation).